# Translating Craft form error message labels

Tags: craft3, form

I am trying to change the label for Craft's form errors. My site local is currently fr_CA, and when I try to submit a form with an error, the error message returned is in french, but the label of the field is in english.

I have managed to translate field labels for plugins, such as the Contact Form plugin by P&T, without any issues by using static translations. All I simply did was create a file with the plugin translation category as a name such as 'contact-form.php' and it works flawlessly.

However, with the forms included in Craft, it doesn't seem to work. For example, with the user registration form, if I submit it without a password, it will come up with an error saying the password needs to have at least 6 characters. Here is the message I receive :

> New Password doit comporter au moins 6 caractères.

The 'New Password' is in english while the rest of the message is in french.

If I try to create a file called 'site.php' or 'app.php' in the translations folder under the right locale, it doesn't translate the 'New Password'. Here is the content of the file :

```
<?php

return [
    'New Password' => 'Nouveau mot de passe'
];
```

It's like none of the translations supplied to Craft are being recognized. Has anyone run into this problem or have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't translate that field. I've tried it too once but it can't be done right now without effort because `craft\elements\User`has no `attributeLabels()` function in it in order to translate the attribute so all Yii2 does is to change `newPassword` to `New Password` but it doesn't translate anything.

You can either submit a feature request for it or do some hacky stuff.

I submitted a feature request [in their git](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3196)

**Edit** 13.08.2018 [This](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/0111023ab679ca53e233ecb300b9faf0e8eb46e0) commit changed it, you'll be able to translate those messages now

Comment: Thank you @robinschambach for the information. Good on you for the feature request, this definitely needs to be addressed. 

Since I am using Ajax to submit the form and display errors, I think I will resort to a simple find and replace in Javascript to translate those fields before displaying the error messages.